# OpenMP parallelization of non-for loop

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

So far I have only used OpenMP to parallelize for loop in C++. However I wonder if I can execute other lines of codes which are not for loops in Parallel.

```
void minimization(int *a, int *x) {
 // this part of the code is dependent of other library.
}

void checkForNaN(int *a){
 // check nan points
}

int main() {
  // read data
  minimization (a,b);
  checkForNaN(x);
}
```

Consider the sample snippet above, whereby `minimization(,)` and `checkForNaN()` are independent that is results of either one does not affect the other once. Is it possible to parallelize it?

I am thinking something like this:

```
  int main() {
      // read data
#pragma omp parallel
    {
      minimization (a,b);
      checkForNaN(x);
     }
}
```

Does it looks correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what OMP Sections is used for :)

```
int main() {
    #pragma omp parallel sections
    {
        #pragma omp section
        { 
            minimization(a,b);
        }

        #pragma omp section
        { 
            checkForNaN(x);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also use OpenMP tasks to achieve the same goal (#pragma omp task). There is a nice discussion on the differences between tasks and sections in  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13788638/difference-between-section-and-task-openmp

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't look correct. it will execute `minimization(a,b);` and `checkForNaN(x);` in all threads you have.

Instead, this will do the parallelization:

```
int main() {
  // read data
  #pragma omp parallel sections
  {
    #pragma omp section
    {
      minimization (a,b);
    }
    #pragma omp section
    {
      checkForNaN(x);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea why you keep posting the exact same answer as me about 1 minute later on posts today :p...

Comment: This answer is not exact same. What @kcc__ 's code does is added.