# Why is my OpenMP parallel Quicksort much slower than my sequential Quicksort?

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, quicksort

I compiled with VSCode G++ -fopenmp on Windows.I am currently trying to show that parallel Quicksort is indeed quicker than Sequential Quicksort, but to no avail. I've changed the number of threads to 2 (reducing possible overhead), and also changing the amount of numbers generated (10,100,10000,100000) but all of them doesn't work. Below is the result time for 10000 data (which is not even close to each other...it's like 500 times slower).
parallel time:4.555 serial time:0.0071298

Below are some code snippets, here is the complete [code](https://pastebin.com/q2xJEKVp).

Partition:

```
int partition(vector<int> &data, int p, int r){
    int pivot = data[p];
    int left = p;
    int right = r;
    while (left < right){
        while (left < r && data[left] <= pivot) ++left;
        while (right >= 0 && data[right] > pivot) --right;
        if (left < right && left <r && right >= 0)
        {
            std::swap(data[left], data[right]);
        }
    }

    if (left < right && left <r && right >= 0)
    {
        std::swap(data[left], data[right]);
    }
    data[p] = data[right];
    data[right] = pivot;
    return right;
}
```

Parallel Quicksort:

```
void ParallelQuickSort (vector<int> &dataList,  int nLower, int nUpper)                                                                                             
{
    if (nLower < nUpper)
    {
        int nSplit = partition (dataList, nLower, nUpper);
        omp_set_num_threads(2);
        #pragma omp parallel sections
        {
            #pragma omp section                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
            ParallelQuickSort (dataList, nLower, nSplit - 1);

            #pragma omp section
            ParallelQuickSort (dataList, nSplit + 1, nUpper);
        }
    }
}
```

Serial Quicksort

```
void SerialQuickSort(vector<int> &dataList,  int nLower, int nUpper)
{
    if (nLower < nUpper)
    {
        int nSplit = partition (dataList, nLower, nUpper);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        SerialQuickSort (dataList, nLower, nSplit - 1);
        SerialQuickSort (dataList, nSplit + 1, nUpper);
    }
}
```

Functions to measure run time/start functions above (not sure if my problem had anything to do with this, so i thought i'd just upload this here):

```
void start_parallel_quicksort(vector<int> &vec,double &parallel_run_time)
{
    double parallel_start_time;
    parallel_start_time=omp_get_wtime();
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp single nowait
        ParallelQuickSort(vec,0,VEC_SIZE-1);
    }
    parallel_run_time=omp_get_wtime()-parallel_start_time;
}

void start_serial_quicksort(vector<int> &vec, duration<double> &serial_run_time)
{
    auto serial_start_time = high_resolution_clock::now();
    SerialQuickSort(vec,0,VEC_SIZE-1);
    auto serial_end_time=high_resolution_clock::now();
    serial_run_time=serial_end_time-serial_start_time;
}
```

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could help me with this. I've searched and tried all the ways I could find on stackoverflow but to no avail-no one had such a huge gap between both methods. Thanks in advance!

Comment: how did you compile? Optimizations turned on? And please include the results as text in the question. Please do not use images for text

Comment: I compiled with VSCode G++ -fopenmp on WIndows. Not sure about what does the optimizations part mean...didn't touch anything related. I've edited it, thanks for the help!

Comment: it's not that i "thought" it wouldn't work- I did try but it does not work. There must be somewhere that I've made a mistake in my code, or else there wouldn't be such a huge difference. Both algorithms have been ran a lot of times by many other OpenMP new learners, and it shouldn't be that huge of a difference. A difference of 2-3 times is logical, but for it to be this huge of a difference means that something is wrong. Eg. I've searched for similar codes with same variables (10000 data, 2 threads) but the time used is only 0.004 for the parallel algorithm.

Comment: I am not into opnemp, but when I remove all openmp pragmas from your parallel code, the runtimes are comparable: https://godbolt.org/z/cdhvn5jc5. Might have something todo with sharing the vector between the two sections. You are only modifying disjunct parts of the vector in the sections, but its still a non-cosnt vector and I suppose openmp adds some measures to synchronize access to it. I am just guessing though

Comment: First, I would use OpenMP _tasks_, not _sections_, see, e.g., this question for some rationale: [Difference between section and task openmp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13789119/580083). Second, parallelization of the recursive tasks only results in a poor scalability since, at high recursion levels, not all the threads/cores are utilized (the very first partitioning employs a single core only). Therefore, for efficient parallel quicksort, you also need parallel partitioning. Moreover, creating tasks and their processing have some overhead. Smaller part should be processed sequentially.

Comment: Also, sorting such small amounts of data will likely not benefit from parallelization, since this always comes with some overhead. Try to work with large amount of data instead (like 10M or 100M elements).

Comment: Try knocking up an implementation using `std::thread` - it won't take you long.  You don't need OMP for this.

Comment: The problem is `#pragma omp parallel sections`. You should *really* not do that in a recursive code, ever. This is called nesting. It creates new thread over and over. This code is basically a fork-bomb with threads. You should **use tasks** in this case instead. You should also use a cut-off strategy to avoid creating too many tasks. Creating 1000 thread to iterate over an array of 1000 items is not reasonable. The same is true with tasks.

Comment: With `#pragma omp parallel` followed by `#pragma omp single nowait`, you tell to OpenMP to start a parallel section of N thread and let `N-1` do nothing. They are not recycled. When threads are waiting actively, this can cause a lot of thread spinning for nothing. There is no reason to use this pattern in a fork-join code. The only use-case where this is useful is for tasks.

Comment: Besides, `high_resolution_clock` should not be used to measure the wall clock time. You should use `steady_clock` (AFAIR, this is mentioned in the C++ standard). The former is not guaranteed to be monotonic.

Comment: @PaulSanders One benefit of OpenMP (besides its simplicity) is that it often quite easy to parallelize a sequential code and the final code can be executed sequentially by just not using the OpenMP compiler flag. This means there is no need to maintain 2 implementations (all pragma can be treated as comment by compilers). This is not true with `std::thread`. Besides OpenMP has an efficient task-scheduler specifically designed for such use-case, while C++ AFAIK does not (and reimplementing it is far from being easy for beginners).

Comment: The problem is obvious. You need to make the partition function parallel. That is not trivial, but not terribly hard either. It's a parallel prefix operation. Search the literature.

Comment: You should realize that depending on the CPU you're using, there's a decent chance a parallel sort simply won't improve performance. A sort basically does comparisons and copying. The comparisons use little CPU time, so it's typically memory bound, even with only one CPU. So you only expect to gain speed if more cores gets you more (effective) bandwidth to memory.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, OpenMP tasks are more suited for this kind of algorithm. You just have to modify the `ParallelQuickSort` routine:

```
void ParallelQuickSort (vector<int> &dataList,  int nLower, int nUpper)                                                                                             
{
    if (nLower < nUpper)
    {
        int nSplit = partition (dataList, nLower, nUpper);
        if (nUpper - nLower >= 128) {
            #pragma omp task default(shared)
            ParallelQuickSort (dataList, nLower, nSplit - 1);
        } else {
            ParallelQuickSort (dataList, nLower, nSplit - 1);
        }
        ParallelQuickSort (dataList, nSplit + 1, nUpper);
        #pragma omp taskwait
    }
}
```

Comments:

- Once the segment is partitioned, just one additional task needs to be created for one of the partitions, while the other one can processed by the current task
- You need a threshold to decide if a new task has to be created or not, because of 2 reasons:

  - the task creation overhead can hide any parallelization benefit for small partitions
  - with a small segment to be sorted, the 2 partitions likely belong to the same cache line (64 or 128 bytes), and synchronizing the cache lines between different cores is very costly.

You have to try various threshold values (I've put an arbitrary 128 elements in the code) to see which one is optimum.

Comment: Note that, without performing partitioning in parallel at top recursion levels, this implementation would have poor scalability.

Comment: @DanielLangr Does it exist an efficient parallel partitioning algorithm that works in place? The ones I can find require a duplication of the input array.

Comment: Yes, it does. Look, e.g., at this implementation provided by so-called Parallel mode of libstdc++: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/parallel/partition.h. Some relevant work is discussed here: https://www.cs.upc.edu/~lfrias/research/parpar/parpar.pdf.